# My .jar executable only works properly when in command line but not when clicking it through the explorer (same location)

Tags: java, swing, command-line

I have a file that i created which only if its accesed by command line it works well. But when clicking it through finder it doesnt work.

I thought it could be a problem of having different JREs but they appear to be the same:

"java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)

Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)"

**Java About:**

[image]

But i doubt they do.
Because when i run it through command line it looks something like this
[image: Running Program]

But when running by clicking at it, it shows in a different size too (the one in the back is the one accesed by finder)
[image]

**Left Cmd Line, Right Finder**

[image]

They don't look the same and I'm 100% sure they are.

My main problem is not the visual per se is that both programs which are the same are not working the same. In this program im trying to read a .ods file, maybe is something when trying to find the file (although ive been doing these for quite some time and never had an issue)

```
File file = new File("P3.ods");

        Sheet sheet=null;
        try {
            sheet = SpreadSheet.createFromFile(file).getSheet(page);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            //sheet=null;
            label.setText("Unable To Read");
            Logger.getLogger(Reader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        }
```

Any help

PS:
The problem is not the visual but they way it should work. I just think that the visuals indicate somethings not right.

Thank you

Comment: It’s possible they are running with different Java versions, or with different HiDPI settings.  The difference you are seeing does not by itself indicate a problem, as long as you are using LayoutManagers and are not using a null layout.

Comment: hmm ... why is this tagged javafx? Looks like Swing .. (taking a closer look after @VGR mentioned LayoutManagers :)

Comment: you are right i messed up and wrote javafx ,it is indeed swing.

Comment: @VGR how can i check the java versions? My main problem here is not they layout as i said but that the program wont work when double clicked but yes when accesed by console, shouldnt it be the same?

Comment: You can always add `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));` to your `main` method, to see the version.  What do you mean by “the program won’t work”?  It apparently worked enough to make a screen shot, did it not?

Comment: @VGR the program reads from an .ods and then sums all the numbers in it, when running the program by command line it will work flawlessly but when opeining it with double click it does nothing, it should be the same thing...

Comment: Edit your question and show the code that reads that .ods file.  I suspect you are reading from a relative file name.  When double-clicking, the current directory can be something unexpected.  It’s best not to rely on relative file names at all.